# NPM package doesn't apear in search in npmjs after upload

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-publish

Several days ago I published a package to npmjs, https://www.npmjs.com/package/pluralize-ru-ts the package is public, i'm pretty sure that the package.json is correct, when i try to `npm i pluralize-ru-ts` package installs fine, i get no errors.
But the package still doesn't apears in npmjs search in npmjs.org and in `npm search pluralize-ru-ts`(returns `No matches found for "pluralize-ru-ts"`)

Any ideas, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried `npm search pluralize-ru-ts` and successfully found you package.

If you are still facing this problem, maybe there are some caching issues.

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMqxI.png)

Comment: It has just appeared in search for me too. Looks like npmjs had some issues.